# Uncaught Thrift Errors

Tags: java, thrift

We hava find a lot of error message like below:

```
[ERROR 2015-07-10 20:00:02.105] [Thread-60] org.apache.thrift.server.TNonblockingServer$FrameBuffer.read(TNonblockingServer.java:542) [Read a frame size of 1246907721, which is bigger than the maximum allowable buffer size for ALL connections.]
[ERROR 2015-07-10 20:13:05.597] [Thread-60] org.apache.thrift.server.TNonblockingServer$FrameBuffer.read(TNonblockingServer.java:542) [Read a frame size of 1246907721, which is bigger than the maximum allowable buffer size for ALL connections.]
[ERROR 2015-07-10 20:20:01.609] [Thread-60] org.apache.thrift.server.TNonblockingServer$FrameBuffer.read(TNonblockingServer.java:542) [Read a frame size of 1246907721, which is bigger than the maximum allowable buffer size for ALL connections.]
[ERROR 2015-07-10 20:30:01.971] [Thread-60] org.apache.thrift.server.TNonblockingServer$FrameBuffer.read(TNonblockingServer.java:542) [Read a frame size of 1246907721, which is bigger than the maximum allowable buffer size for ALL connections.]
[ERROR 2015-07-10 20:40:02.481] [Thread-60] org.apache.thrift.server.TNonblockingServer$FrameBuffer.read(TNonblockingServer.java:542) [Read a frame size of 1246907721, which is bigger than the maximum allowable buffer size for ALL connections.]
[ERROR 2015-07-10 20:50:02.425] [Thread-60] org.apache.thrift.server.TNonblockingServer$FrameBuffer.read(TNonblockingServer.java:542) [Read a frame size of 1246907721, which is bigger than the maximum allowable buffer size for ALL connections.]
```

An exception occer every ten minutes, in mulit service on mulit server; but we don't no who request this.

Then we use tcpdump to find where the request come. We found something like below:

```
20:50:02.424728 IP localhost.32370 > localhost.9901: Flags [S], seq 697614673, win 32768, options [mss 16396,sackOK,TS val 3592557674 ecr 3592557167,nop,wscale 7], length 0
20:50:02.424744 IP localhost.9901 > localhost.32370: Flags [S.], seq 1999432280, ack 697614674, win 32768, options [mss 16396,sackOK,TS val 3592557674 ecr 3592557674,nop,wscale 7], length 0
20:50:02.425734 IP localhost.9901 > localhost.32370: Flags [R.], seq 1, ack 8, win 256, options [nop,nop,TS val 3592557675 ecr 3592557674], length 0
```

The request context length 7 are: "JRMI..K".

Because the request gone very fast, so we can't use lsof or netstat to find out which process send it.

So, is there any we to find out what happing?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which port is your Thrift server listening in?

Comment: What is connecting to it from port 32370?